# display a picture which filename has changes in php

Tags: php, database, image

I have a problem to display pictures that can be uploaded on my website. During the upload process I change the name of the file, store the picture in a folder and the file name in a database. I present my code below. Many thanks in advance to those who will have a look:

the form to upload the picture:

```
<form method="post" action="PicPost.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="Pic">Upload your pic: (JPG, JPEG PNG ou GIF  | max. 1 Mo) :</label><br />
     <input type="hidden" name="maxsize" value="1048576" />
     <input type="file" name="Pic" id="Pic" />

 <p>
   <label>Tags
   <input type="text" name="Tags" id="Tags" />
   </label>
   <br />

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
      </p>
  </form>
```

The code to complete the upload in PicPost.php:

```
 <?php
$maxsize = '1048576';

 if ($_FILES['Pic']['error'] > 0) $erreur = "Error";

 if ($_FILES['Pic']['size'] > $maxsize) $erreur = "The file is too big";

 $extensions_valides = array( 'jpg' , 'jpeg' , 'gif' , 'png' );
 $extension_upload = strtolower(  substr(  strrchr($_FILES['Pic']     ['name'], '.')  ,1)  );
  if ( in_array($extension_upload,$extensions_valides) ) echo "Correct extension";

 $name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

 $resultat = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Pic']['tmp_name'],$name);
 if ($resultat) echo "Upload successful";

 try
 {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', '');
 }
 catch (Exception $e)
 {
die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
 }
 $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO picdb (Picture, Tags)
 VALUES(?, ?)');
 $req->execute(array($name, $_POST['Tags']));
```

The code to search a picture in the database through tags:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="SearchPost.php">
<label>
<input type="text" name="Search" id="Search" />
</label>
<label>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Search" />
</label>
</form>
```

The code to display the picture searched in SearchPost.php:

```
try
{
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', '');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}


 $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT Picture FROM picdb WHERE
 Tags=\''.$_POST['Search'].'\'');

  while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())


 echo "<img src=".$donnees['Picture']."/>";

 $reponse->closeCursor();
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I was just giving votes. I accepted other answers. I do not know where can I add error handling, I have already few ones in the upload process (second code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the new filename in the database, in another field, or the one you have already.

You're storing the original filename

Comment: Hi case 1352. It's strange, I just checked, the filename is correctly replaced by an alphanumeric name both in the database and the folder.

Comment: is the path to the folder correct? the html youre producing is assuming the image is in the same folder as the php script

Comment: Yes, for the moment I am storing it in the same folder just for test purpose. Once it will work, I will create a special folder for pictures.

Comment: Do you mean if the line "echo "<img src=".$donnees['Picture']."/>";" retrieve the name correctly? I think that's where the problem is. I do not know how I should insert the variable correctly in this line to display the picture correctly. When I write "echo $donnees['Picture'];", I get the correct filenames.

Comment: when you view the source of searchpost.php after it has been displayed  to the browser, is the correct filename in the html

Comment: Haaaa you found it! I didn,t thought about checking the filename this way (sorry I am a rookie...). There were " ' " missing in my line echo. The correct code is `echo '<img src='".$donnees['Picture']." '/>";` Thank you very much for your time and help case1352!